# Add checkbox button

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox

I'm creating list view with checkboxes, and I need in this a button that adds next checkbox in my form app. I know how to add single box, but idk how to make a loop that will helps me to add next checkboxes. Here, I give u a piece of code. At the start I have 24 checkboxes, next must be on 612 px position.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         CheckBox box;
         box = new CheckBox();
         box.AutoSize = true;
         box.Location = new Point(30, 612);
         this.Controls.Add(box);
    }
```

Comment: Need a loop?  Use a loop.  Change the location in the loop.  Or use a FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: Can you give me a code where you used a "FlowLayoutPanel"? Sorry, I'm a novice.

Comment: No.  I gave you the information you need.  Do the work.  This is not a "give me the code" type of website.

Comment: Just use a `for` loop, and increment the value of the Point parameter to the next position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that your checkbox exist within a button click event, is that what you truly want?

You can loop, in this manner:

```
var coordinates = new List<Coordinate>();
foreach(var coordinate in coordinates)
{
      Checkbox checkbox = CreachCheckbox(coordinate.X, coordinate.Y);
      this.Controls.Add(checkbox);
}

protected Checkbox CreateCheckbox(int x, int y)
{
     var checkbox = new Checkbox();
     checkbox.AutoSize = true;
     checkbox.Location = new Point(x, y);
     return checkbox;
}
```

You simply need to build an object called `Coordinates` with your desired locations, then you would iterate through those objects for each of your `Checkbox` which will populate based on your desired positioning.